# Prisma warn 10 instances

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

I'm getting the following warning in the console:

```
warn(prisma-client) There are already 10 instances of Prisma Client actively running.
```

I've tried to follow the prisma documentantion to solve this warning, explained here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/connection-management#prismaclient-in-long-running-applications

So I've created a file with the following code:

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')
const prisma = new PrismaClient()
export default prisma
```

And then import prisma in the api like this:

```
import prisma from "@/backend/db"
```

But the warning persists.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would need to instantiate PrismaClient like this:

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const globalForPrisma = global as unknown as { prisma: PrismaClient }

export const prisma =
  globalForPrisma.prisma ||
  new PrismaClient({
    log: ['query'],
  })

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') globalForPrisma.prisma = prisma
```

This should fix the issue that you are getting. Here's a [reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/troubleshooting-orm/help-articles/nextjs-prisma-client-dev-practices) for it.